Unable to Print Label with Dymo LableWriter 450
I'm using Laravel 10 now I try to Print label with Dymo LableWriter 450 with sdk but it give me CORS error can Anyone help me ?
function loadLabel() {
            if (dymo.label.framework) {
                dymo.label.framework.init(function() {
                    var labelXmlPath = '/Label1.dymo';

                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open('GET', labelXmlPath, true);
                    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                                var labelXml = xhr.responseText;

                                if (labelXml) {
                                    var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);

                                    console.log('Label loaded successfully:', label);
                                    console.log('Label XML:', label.getLabelXml());

                                    if (label.isDCDLabel()) {
                                        console.log('This is a DCD label.');
                                    } else {
                                        console.log('This is not a DCD label.');
                                    }

                                                                   

                                    var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
                                    if (printers.length == 0) {
                                        throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";
                                    }

                                    var printerName = "";
                                    for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i) {
                                        var printer = printers[i];
                                        if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter") {
                                            printerName = printer.name;
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }

                                    label.print(printerName);
                                } else {
                                    console.error(
                                        'Error loading label XML. The content is empty or undefined.');
                                }
                            } else {
                                console.error('Error loading label XML. HTTP status:', xhr.status);
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    xhr.send();
                });
            } else {
                console.error('DYMO Label Framework is not available.');
            }
        }

this is my code but it give me error how can I handle CORS please give me any solution . Any other sdk or any other solution with third party if anyone work with this
